# How to scroll expandable list view with parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Problem with scrolling expandable list view with complete layout.

I am trying to create a register page which has text fields such as username and password , and also expandable list views as shown in pictures .

[image] [image]

Moment the page loads one can see Register new button at bottom , but if I press on expandable list view I can’t scroll down to bottom until I collapse my list view .

Following is my layout file attached with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dip">

          <!-- Full Name Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Full Name"/>

          <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_fullname"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
          <!--  Email Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Email"/>

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/reg_email"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
              android:ems="10"
              android:singleLine="true" >

              <requestFocus />
          </EditText>

          <!-- Password Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Password"/>

          <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

        <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/cat_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ExpandableListView>
          <!-- Register Button -->

        <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
              android:text="Register New Account" />


          <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/link_to_login"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:text="Already has account! Login here"
              android:textColor="#025f7c"
              android:textSize="20dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to know , what can be the possible problem with layout file ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in two different layouts.
That is, I'd recommend having:

```
- RelativeLayout
  -- ScrollView android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:above="@+id/layout1"
    --- LinearLayout  (basically what you have above, most of it)
  -- LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout1" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    --- RegisterButton
```

Have the LinearLayout with the register button align parent bottom.
Have the scroll view align parent top and above the lower layout.

Comment: cannot do align parent bottom to a single button so applied to parent linear layout of button, and then I am unable to align parent top my scroll view , as a result expandable list view is unable to scroll. Thanks for the help and giving your time.

Comment: I updated with some more explicit layout options. Again, keep everything you had in your original layout in the linear layout in the scroll view, _except_ for the button, which goes in the new layout outside the scroll view.

Comment: Oh, and updated with a little more formatting - I think my original formatting got lost, so I added extra leading dashes to show parenting, might have been the problem.